# Clearing asp.net textbox using javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, textbox

I have a two textboxes in ASP.net.  When one is clicked on, I want the other to clear.

Here is my code for the textboxes:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="box1" onfocus="clearBox2()"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Textbox runat="server" ID="box2"></asp:Textbox>
```

And my javascript on the same page:

```
function clearBox2() {
     document.getElementById("<%=box2.ClientID%>").value = '';
 }
```

I don't know why but this isn't working.  I've managed to verify through chrome developer tools that the `value='';` line is being called.  I've also attempted toe erase it through jQuery like this:

```
 $("#<%=box1.ClientID%>").focus(function(){
     alert("testing");
});
```

But the alert doesn't get called.  Chrome developer tools isn't showing any javascript syntax errors.

Would anyone happen to know what is happening?

Comment: Its working at my end. Try to clear cache from your browser and try again

Comment: Try giving the textbox a class just to be sure and give that to the function... ASP doesn't mess up the DOM of classes like it does ID's.
<asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="box1" ID="box1" onfocus="clearBox2()"></asp:TextBox>
 $(".box1").focus(function(){
     alert("testing");
});

Answer (score 0):

As far as your jquery not working, it could be how you're attaching the focus handler to the textbox, if you're doing it in the  tag it should look like...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#<%=box1.ClientID%>").focus(function(){
     alert("testing");
   });      
});
</script>
```

If you're not doing it in the  then make sure you're inserting the script AFTER the textbox in the html.

I do think your first example should work.  Not sure exactly what's going on without seeing more of the source.

Answer (score 0):

Try  this

```
function clearBox2() {
 $("#<%=box2.ClientID%>").val('');
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yjXkr/)

Comment: That probably won't work due to ASP changing ID's to something like "maincontent_box2"

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the textbox a class just to be sure and give that to the function...

ASP doesn't mess up the DOM of classes like it does ID's.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="box1" ID="box1" onfocus="clearBox2()"></asp:TextBox> 

<script>$(".box1").focus(function(){ alert("testing"); });</script>
```